# Automatic installation Roboto font to all view (pre ICS)

Tags: android, view, fonts, automation

Now for each view on the layout I write

`Typeface robotoFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto.ttf"); 
myView.setTypeface(robotoFont);`

Want to pre-ICS versions of Android font has been applied to all view. How to do this easier?
There is an option to extend all classes and set the font, but it is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the RobotoTextView library:

https://github.com/johnkil/Android-RobotoTextView

It allows you to use a huge variety of Roboto types on pre-ICS devices.